# CATransform3D Animation Set X Axis

Tags: ios, cocoa

I have a CATransform3D Animation designed to replace the Push animation currently being used in my app. Currently, it rotates as if the X axis were in the centre of the layer/view. However, I want the X axis to be at the edge of the screen so it flips out of the screen. My current code is: -

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / 500;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 1.57, 0, 1, 0);
    self.view.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

I'm new to Core Graphics and such, so any pointers, tips, where I'm going wrong will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `anchorPoint` of the layer. Use the following piece of code before `beginAnimations:context:` method.

```
CGRect frame = self.view.layer.frame;
self.view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.f, 0.5f);
self.view.layer.frame = frame;
```

This will change the `anchorPoint` of the layer without changing the layer position. The rotation animation will be done around the axis that passes from the anchor point.

Comment: That causes the layer to move down to the bottom right corner of the screen. I'd like it to stay in the same spot but have it animate as if you were turning a page.

Comment: I got it working by setting the anchorPoint to 0.f, 0.f. If you edit the answer to reflect that, I'll be happy to vote it up.